# Render Hosting "Server unhealthy"

Tags: node.js, hosting

My hosting service (render) is suddenly returning a "server unhealthy, exited with status 1" and I'm not sure what to do.

```
Nov 29 03:45:37 PM     │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                                                                                                    │
Nov 29 03:45:37 PM     │                                                                                                                                         │
Nov 29 03:45:37 PM     │   Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the                                                         │
Nov 29 03:45:37 PM     │   current system                                                                                                                        │
Nov 29 03:45:37 PM     │   Expected directory: node-v83-linux-x64-glibc                                                                                          │
Nov 29 03:45:37 PM     │   Found: [node-v64-linux-x64-glibc]                                                                                                     │
Nov 29 03:45:37 PM     │   This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
```

I attempted to run the suggested npm rebuild in the shell but had no luck. Help is greatly appreciated. Is it because of the outdated node version that this project is using? If so is keeping this project running on this version going to be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means that the installed version of the gRPC binary package does not match the system it is running on. In particular, your specific error means that the package was installed with Node 10, but your code is running on Node 14. Usually, that can be corrected by running `npm rebuild` on the system where you are running the code, but if not, you can explicitly install for your target system using `npm rebuild --target=14.0.0`, or if that doesn't work, `npm install --target=14.0.0`.

Please note that the `grpc` package is deprecated. If possible, it is recommended that you switch to the `@grpc/grpc-js` package, which does not have issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm rebuild` should recompile and rebuild any native binary dependencies to match your current Node.js version (in this case, Node.js 14), potentially resolving the version mismatch issue.

Please note that running `npm rebuild` might require administrative privileges in some cases, so you might need to use `sudo npm rebuild` on Unix-like systems if you encounter permission issues.

Comment: Please read Stack Overflow's policies on chatGPT content. https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy